# handle tests using TAP::Harness, how to print output when test exits

Tags: perl, testing, junit, formatter, tap-harness

I am trying the whole day to find out the answer, but I didn't find anything.
I wrote some tests using **test::more** (test1.t, test2.t, test3.t ...).
and I wrote a main perl script (main.pl) that handles all the tests using **TAP::Harness** and print the output in a JUnit format using **formatter_class => 'TAP::Formatter::JUnit**.
In my tests I use the BAIL_OUT function.
The problem is that when a test is bailed out, the main script also exits and there is no output at all. If, for example test3.t bailed_out, I need to see the results for test1.t and test2.t. how can I do that?

I can't use exit or die instead of BAIL_OUT because I don't want the other tests to continue. (If test3.t was BAIL_OUT I don't want that test4.t will run.)

can someone please help me?
I need to see the results for the tests that were running before the bailed out test.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`Test::More`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3A%3AMore) docs:

> BAIL_OUT($reason);
>
> Indicates to the harness that things are going so badly all testing should terminate.
>   This includes the running of any additional test scripts.

So that explains why your suite aborts.

You might want to consider `die_on_fail` from [`Test::Most`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3A%3AMost), or `skip_all`, depending on the reason for the BAIL_OUT.

EDIT: Looks like Test::Builder doesn't have any intention of printing out a summary when it exits on "catastrophic failure" [according to the source code](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MSCHWERN/Test-Simple-0.98/lib/Test/Builder.pm):

```
sub BAIL_OUT {
    my( $self, $reason ) = @_;

    $self->{Bailed_Out} = 1;
    $self->_print("Bail out!  $reason");
    exit 255;
}

# Don't do an ending if we bailed out.
if( $self->{Bailed_Out} ) {
    $self->is_passing(0);
    return;
}
```

However, that `Bailed_Out` flag is only ever used to consider printing out summary diagnostics, and since `Test::More` exposes the underlying `Test::Builder` object, you can probably just tweak the `BAIL_OUT` subroutine and no set this flag.  All untested, of course; YMMV.

Comment: But I do need BAIL_OUT, because I do not need to run all other tests. if I use die or skip, other tests will continue running. I use BAIL_OUT when the test fail because the whole build failed and there is no reason to keep testing.
It is ok that the suite aborts, but can I see the results for the tests that ran before I bailed out?

Comment: and I wish that only the relevant test suite will be aborted, why the main script with all previous test suits need to vanish as well?

Comment: That sounds nice, but how can I change the flag value?

Comment: And, it seems that even if I will change it to 'Flase' the program will still exit without printing the summery, am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing in all tests to one TAP::Harness, you need to pass in one test at a time to the Harness in case of a BAIL_OUT

I haven't seen your code, so here is a sample of what I mean. Adjust to include the formatter and whatever else you need.

```
use TAP::Harness;

my $harness = TAP::Harness->new({ merge => 0 });
my $tests = ['t/test1.t', 't/test2.t'];

foreach my $test (@$tests) {
    eval {
        $harness->runtests([$test]);
    }; if ($@) {
        # create new harness object if the previous fails catastrophically.
        $harness = TAP::Harness->new({ merge => 0 });
    }
}
```